# Ubuntu 15.10 - How to install live wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

How do I download live wallpapers on my new ubuntu 15.10 machine?

```
sudo apt-get install livewallpaper
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package livewallpaper
```

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the launchpad site for the daily release of [livewallpaper](https://launchpad.net/~fyrmir/+archive/ubuntu/livewallpaper-daily), you will find that it supports up to Ubuntu Vivid, but not yet Ubuntu Wily.  You will need to find another solution for changing wallpaper, or compile the program yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You did not find the package because it is not part of the standard software repository.

But there is a personal package archive (PPA) that contains it: `ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily`.

See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/05/animated-wallpaper-adds-live-backgrounds-to-linux-distros for a good overview.

The commands to install they mention are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install livewallpaper
sudo apt-get install livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator
```