# Ubuntu 16.10 how to install some Live Wallpapers?

Tags: desktop-background, 16.10

Is there any possibility to get some live Wallpapers??
i tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily`
but it seems to be to old.

Comment: Did you do: "sudo apt-get install livewallpaper livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator
" after "sudo apt-get update"?

Comment: jes i did @PatrickNegus

Comment: Any help here? "[Ubuntu 15.10 - How to install live wallpaper](http://askubuntu.com/a/726296/38585)"

Answer (score 1):

I had no trouble getting it to work with 16.10.

After adding the repository, I had to navigate to System Settings > Software & Updates. Then under the "Other Software" tab you have to edit the livewallpaper repository's settings where it says "distribution". Change it from "yakkety" to "xenial". Only then could I successfully download the packages.

Log out and back in after launching the program to see the live-wallpaper indicator.